# More than one accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I know that in [moms4mom.com](http://moms4.mom.com) you can accept more than one answer. What are people's thoughts on this? I am all for it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been asked and answered on Meta.SO many times, so I'll just point you to a couple of them over there:

- [Woudn't it make sense to have more than one answer acceptable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6914/woudnt-it-make-sense-to-have-more-than-one-answer-acceptable)
- [Allow more than one answer to be accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17257/allow-more-than-one-answer-to-be-accepted)

(Short version: Sorry, but no.)